# Attach entity history/changes to the entity as OneToMany association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, one-to-many

I've an entity `Order`, with a property `events` which should contain a list of all changes made to this entity.

The `Order` class:

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    // more stuff...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *      targetEntity="OrderEvent",
     *      mappedBy="order",
     *      cascade={"persist", "merge"}
     * )
     */
    protected $events;

    // more stuff...
}
```

The `OrderEvent` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrderEvent
{
    // more stuff...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Order", inversedBy="events")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $order;

    // more stuff...
}


class OrderLifecycle
{
    public function preUpdate(Order $order, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $changes = $args->getEntityChangeSet();

        if (!empty($changes)) {

            $event = new OrderEvent();

            $event->setOrder($order)
                ->setChanges($changes);

            $order->addEvent($event);

            return $event;
        }
    }
}
```

But [according to the doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate), the `preUpdate` method should not be used to change associations.

What is the recommended way to do things like this one?

I am using Zend Framework 2, but I think that's not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case you could use `PostUpdate` event. In that case you are sure that the `update` action was successful and you can do what you want; add the new `OrderEvent` instance to your `$events` collection.

### EDIT

You are not the first one implementing such thing. Maybe you should check existing examples and see how they deal with this (or even consider using it). For example [the Gedmo `Loggable` solution](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md).

With this extension you can mark entities as loggable with a simple `@annotiation`:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class Order
{
    // Your class definition
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that on `postUpdate` there is no information about the changes available. How would you handle this? My first idea is to store the changes in an (maybe static) class property. But this seems not to be very nice!?

Comment: You are not the first one implementing such thing. Maybe you should check existing examples and see how they deal with this. For example the [Gedmo `Loggable` solution](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md)

Comment: Now the only missing thing is `OneToMany` associations, like in my case `orderItems`. I would like to have the changes of the orderItems inside the order history. But I think I will change my existing code to use the orderItem history separately. Thank you!